Error encountered during CLI Lambda function deployment using DotNet WebApp
I am trying to deploy my DotNet WebAPI to AWS lambda using CLI.
I have followed the process according to the below tutorial link -
Serverless ASP.NET Core Web API with AWS Lambda
When I execute
dotnet lambda deploy-function
the zip file gets generated but then I encounter error after I provide the Function Name for AWS Lambda function name)
Error retrieving configuration for function MindzenBackend: Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.

image1
image2
I have created the Lambda function and have assigned IAM roles to it. Also when I upload the zip manually to AWS lambda, it works.
Could you please help guys.
Regards,
Abhik Dey

Created secure connection with AWS and my machine.
Tried uploading the zip file manually to AWS lambda which works
The command line is not working.


Have you configured AWS profile locally? If not then just run aws configure to set it up.
